# R: Loop to remove NAs only removes some NAs?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, structure

I wrote a loop in order to remove values declared as "N.A.".
I have two dataframes `vis1` and `vis2` which have matching rows with "N.A.". Now, I would like to remove rows containing these values.
This is my loop:

```
for(i in 1:dim(vis1)[1]){
    if(isTRUE(unlist(vis2[i, 166]) == "N.A.")){
        vis1<- vis1[-i,]
        vis2<- vis2[-i,]
    } 
}
```

The loop only removes like 80 % of these values. If I run it again, it removes 10 more % and so on.

Btw, the variables are of class dataframe --> character.

```
str(vis1)
'data.frame':   84 obs. of  166 variables:
...
$ a                   : chr  "8" "2" "2" "2" ...
$ b                   : chr  "38" "15" "66" "3" ...
...
```

Does anyone have any idea why the loop does not remove all of my values? It can not be because some values have a different name, they all have the same name.

Thanks in advance!

## EDIT

I reordered my dataframe, so it looks like that:

```
vis1[166]

5                735
6               2765
7               1129
8               9774
9               1052
10               780
20              N.A.
```

But, if I index `dat[5, 166]` I get 1052 and not 735. However, could this be a reason?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `x[x[, 166] != "N.A.", ]` on both data.frames?

Comment: Can you share the data or post the result of `str (vis1)`, `str (vis2)`?

Comment: @Liman . I did, their structure is identical

Comment: @RomanLuštrik it worked. Thank you! However, I wonder about this issue. The loop should do the same job....

Comment: I think the problem with the loop is you are removing elements and shortening the vector while you are iterating through the loop.  It is likely the consecutive rows with NA were not being removed. Instead of going from first to last, reverse the direction and start from the last element and move to the first.

Comment: Note that `1:dim(vis1)[1]` is only evaluated once, at the beginning of the loop. As you keep removing rows, the indices `i` will be reffering to rows that might no longer exist (past the last row of the new df) or that are in other places (closer to the first row).

Comment: Also, in `dat[5, 166]` the `5` is no longer a row *number*, it's, as always, a row *name*. These can be equal to one another but this is not the case since you have removed rows. Try `dat["5", 166]` instead. Bottom line, @RomanLuštrik vectorized code is not only idiomatic but is also much safer. An alternative could be `is.na(vis1[[166]]) <- vis1[[166]] == "N.A."` followed by `vis1 <- vis1[complete.cases(vis1), ]`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Dave2e. I did not consider this but it makes sense.

Comment: and also thank you, @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you cancel a row the index is not properly adjusted.

Try the following:

```
`while.na.deleter <- function(df){
  i=1
  while(i < nrow(df)+1){
    if(any(is.na(df[i,]))){
      df <- df[-c(i), ]}
    else{i=i+1}
  }
  return(df)
}`
```

Anyway, there are several methods to cancel rows.

```
na.omit
```

is the fastest I think.